# Excel coloured line chart for grouped data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel how do I create a line Chart with each simulator being its own coloured line showing Calculation time (and potentially another colour for its Total time).

Axis X = Rounds
Axix Y = Time (linear from smallest time to largest?)

Thanks

```
SimulatorName                   Round               TotalTime           CalculationTime
IndexedSimulator                1                   9                   2
ListSimulator                   1                   3998                25
HashSetSimulator                1                   25                  24
IndexedSimulator                2                   1                   0
ListSimulator                   2                   26                  23
HashSetSimulator                2                   29                  27
IndexedSimulator                3                   1                   0
ListSimulator                   3                   41                  38
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can first run a pivottable and then run a chart on it:

[image]

I used only the calculated time in this screenshot and you can change the settings of the pivottable to remove those grand totals if you don't want to see them. If you don't know how to do a pivot table (even after reading the documentation), leave me a comment and I'll put some explanation.